# css height standards mode

Tags: css, html, standards, height

Hello and nice to meet you.
I would like to ask the following.

```
<body>
    <div style="border:1px solid #ff0000">
        <pre>dfssdgfdsgsd sdgsdg
        sgdsdsgsdg</pre>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid #ff0" id="secondDiv">
        ggg
    </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to make #secondDiv to take 100%(in height) of the remaining vertical space?
I don't want to use min-height(doesn't work in ie) or javascript.
Complete html http://paste2.org/p/1177197
Thanks.
ps:I know that there exist a lot of related questions so i'm sorry in case of a duplicate.

Comment: `min-height` only doesn't work in IE6.

Comment: Does the first div have a fixed height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use fixed height for the top div then it is easy to work around the second div, by using absolute positioning.

**CSS**

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#head{
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  height:50px;
}
#content{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;

  border:1px solid #ff0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="head">
        <pre>dfssdgfdsgsd sdgsdg
        sgdsdsgsdg</pre>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        ggg
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/RVTpT/

Comment: of course...
in case that the height of #head isn't fixed do you think of a pure css solution?
btw thanks :)

Comment: @tasoss, it is not possible with pure css. A trick (*depending on requirement*) is to put the `#header` inside of the 100% height `#content`, **without** absolute positioning. Will not work if you want to use borders like in your example though..

Answer (score 0):

add `#secondDiv { height:100%; }` to your CSS.

I believe in order for this to work in IE you need to set

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

as well

Comment: @Gaby:no it doesn't...Do you think of using 20% for the first div and 80% for the second?A possible alternative(instead of having no height at all) could be a height measured in pixels for example.

Comment: No this doesn't help. #secondDiv will have 100% of the body ignoring that the first div is there.

Comment: @tasoss, the problem is that if you define a height (*in whatever unit `%` or `px`*) it means that the height is fixed.